# App development for Google Store

Tags: android, vb.net, vb6, google-play

I asked this question in Android Enthusiasts but I don't know if that is the correct place to ask. I'm looking to build a simple application that I'd like to post to Play Store.

However, my programming knowledge is limited to VB6, VB.net, VBA - primarily VB6. After doing some brief research it looks like I might not be able to build it in VB, but would C# work? Any advice?

Comment: Using Xamarin.com you can use C# to build native Android apps

Comment: Why not learn something new? VB was voted the most-dreaded technology in the Stack Overflow 2016 survey. I wouldn't limit yourself to C# either, it requires additional libraries and weight just so you can use a non-native language.

Comment: You can use web technologies (HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT) with Apache Cordova or C# on Xamarin or the Unity 3D game engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with learning Java first since all Android applications are Java based. After that, you can start learning to create applications on Android Studio.

Comment: developer.android.com/training will teach you all you need about Android development. Nice tutorials and examples